# Create Deployment based on event in another deployment

Tags: kubernetes

I am building an application with 2 different pods in my GKE Cluster one of them is redis another on is Java.

I am insert some commands in Redis, once the command is inserted I want the java deployment to get created. Currently I am running a job every 15mins to read the activity in Redis. I want to Optimize this.

I tried calling Kubenetes API but not working then I tried Argo workflow that also is not working, any other way of doing this

Comment: The Kubernetes API would be the right building block; what code do you have now and what's going wrong?  Would having a long-running Deployment running a task-queueing system, or a messaging system like RabbitMQ, meet your higher-level goals without needing to interact with the Kubernetes API?

Comment: As david asked many things to share so someone could answer, argo workflow is good else share the code you are running of java to interact with API of k8s

Answer (score 0):

Log based events can be used to trigger cloud functions which will create your deployment in GKE. Write all your redis deployment events to log files and when the desired output gets generated it will trigger your GCP cloud function which in turn creates a java deployment in your GKE environment. For more information on how to write event driven functions follow this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/write-event-driven-functions).